# Async task raises NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, async-await, .net-4.5

I continue to struggle with Windows Phone programming. :)

When invoking the method:

```
public static async Task<string> ConvertToBase64(this BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    RandomAccessStreamReference rasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bitmapImage.UriSource);
    var streamWithContent = await rasr.OpenReadAsync();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[streamWithContent.Size];
    var result = await streamWithContent.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)streamWithContent.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result.ToArray()))
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

from

```
public async void SetPhotoString(BitmapImage bi)
{
    photoBase64 = await bi.ConvertToBase64();
}
```

in class `Offer` from the button callback:

```
public async void Post()
{
    var newOffer = new Offer()
    {
        BookAuthor = Author,
        BookTitle = Title,
        CurrencyWorth = Price,
        Description = Description,
        StartedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Status = OfferStatus.Added
    };
    newOffer.SetPhotoString(Photo);//this line throws an excp.
    var result = await offerService.AddOffer(newOffer);
    if (result != null)
        ClearFormula();
}
```

I get the "NotImplementedException" raised. I guess I am doing something wrong with that async calls, but I have no idea what.

Exception details:
`message: The method or operation is not implemented.`

```
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SecondHandBookshop.Shared.Helpers.BitmapImageExtensions.<ConvertToBase64>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SecondHandBookshop.Shared.Models.Offer.<SetPhotoString>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Further info:
Photo is a BitmapImage property of my AddNewOfferViewModel, that acts as a source for the Image control. It is captured from the camera on the wirtual device:

```
public async void TakeAPhoto()
    {
        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("TestPhoto.jpg",
            CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);
        Photo = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
        await MediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Photo);
        ShowCaptureFrame = false;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowCaptureFrame);
    }
```

when I replace the line that gives and exception with:

```
newOffer.PhotoBase64 = await Photo.ConvertToBase64();
```

I get an exception:

```
    Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SecondHandBookshop.Shared.Helpers.BitmapImageExtensions.<ConvertToBase64>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SecondHandBookshop.WindowsPhone.ViewModels.AddOfferViewModel.<Post>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: [Avoid async void methods](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) - and I can't see any reason why you would *want* `SetPhotoString` to be async void.

Comment: BitmapImage is achieved by capturing image from camera.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I get `Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.` exception when using `newOffer.PhotoBase64 = await Photo.ConvertToBase64();`

Comment: `.SetPhotoString(Photo);`... what and where is `Photo` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `Photo` is properly implemented?

Comment: @salniro Photo is the BitmapImage captchured from the camera. I actually started to doubt whether this is a good image, since it is taken by wirtual device. But it binds to Image control source just fine and gets displayed as an image with two zero's in a circle.

Comment: @EmiliaSzymańska where do you have `Photo` defined. This looks suspicious, especially since it's capitalized. Are you sure you are passing the object instance?

Comment: Can you step into `ConvertToBase64` extension method and define what exactly line will through the exception synchroniously? You can do that by removing all `async/await` stuff.

Comment: @VMAtm It looks like this: scr.hu/0auv/p8cu2

Comment: Are there any inner exceptions in this one?

Comment: Does your code works synchroniously?

Comment: @VMAtm It does not. I came to conclusion that there is something wrong with the conversion to base64 itself, and that NotImplementedException just masks a real problem, not connected to synchronization. I am not sure what to do with this question, since now the title does not correspond to the real problem, it should be "what is wrong with this conversion method". Should I close the question somehow?

Comment: You should ask another one question, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your code for `ConvertToBase64` isn't being awaited? This is completely wrong, as the [`async void`](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) construction.

Try to change your code to something like this:

```
newOffer.photoBase64 = await SetPhotoString(Photo);//this line throws an excp.

public async Task<string> SetPhotoString(BitmapImage bi)
{
    return await bi.ConvertToBase64();
}
```

Also, what line of the `ConvertToBase64` method does throw the exception?
Does exception occur with continious operation?
If no, then some of the classes you are using for the `async` code didn't implement properly the [`GetAwaiter`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html) method, which leads you to the exception.
If yes, than the problem is in `Photo` property you didn't show us. May be there is some not implemented method in your code.

Comment: I marked this an answer since the real problem is not connected to asynchronous calls, which I discovered running it synchronously. Thanks for help, I posted another question connected to the base64 conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133552/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-when-opening-randomaccessstream

Answer (score 0):

Try return a Task in your ConvertToBase64 extension method.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result.ToArray()))
{
    return Task.FromResult(Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: That gives a compiler error: `Cannot convert type Task<string> to return type 'string'`

Comment: I forgot the await keyword inmediately after return.

Comment: This leads me back to not implemented exception.

Comment: And add the await keyword to your call of ConvertToBase64 as VMAtm said.